# How to fix 'NameError: name 'russ_yaz' is not defined'

Tags: python, pdf, kivy, python-3.7

I want to open a book in PDF viewer to create a library of books for Android. When you press the button should open the reader with the desired PDF book. But when you click the button, an error appears. NameError: name 'russ_yaz' is not defined

I tried to solve the problem by changing the location of russ_yaz, but nothing changed.

```py
class SubjectsScreen10(Screen):
    def russ_yaz(self):
        self.fn = 'Дудников, А.В Русский язык.pdf'
```

```
Button1:
    text:"Russian"
    on_press: russ_yaz(SubjectScreen10.fn)
```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

    if len(argv) > 1:
        fn = argv[1]
    root = PDFDocumentWidget(source=self.fn, cols=1)
    runTouchApp(root)
```

```py
from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp 
from shutil import rmtree 
from binascii import b2a_hex 
from os import write, close 
from threading import Thread 
from kivy.config import Config 
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage 
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser 
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator 
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument, PDFNoOutlines 
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter 
from pdfminer.layout import ( 
LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine, LTFigure, LTImage, LTChar, LTCurve, 
LTLine, LTRect, 
) 

from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.clock import Clock 
import kivy.graphics 
from kivy.graphics import Mesh, Color 
from kivy.graphics.tesselator import Tesselator 

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.image import Image 
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 

from kivy.properties import ( 
StringProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty, AliasProperty, 
DictProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, ColorProperty, 
) 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.config import Config
```

I want to open the book in pdf-viewer

Comment: When posting code, please post a minimal runnable example. This example includes enormous amounts of code that isn't relevant, and it isn't even complete/runnable.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to solve the problem by changing the location of russ_yaz, but nothing changed.

Presumably you never put it in an appropriate location.

```
Button1:
    text:"Russian"
    on_press: russ_yaz(SubjectScreen10.fn)
```

This code isn't trying to fetch it from anywhere in particular, just look up the function name in the local namespace. This is basically just wrong, you need to decide where in particular it's defined and then refer to it from there. For instance, if you make `russ_yaz` a method of the Button1 class then you could do `self.russ_yaz(SubjectScreen10.fn)`, assuming SubjectScreen10 *is* defined.